# How to export iOS contacts with photos?

Tags: ios, icloud, vcf-vcard

Because of many apps needing my contacts (Thunderbird, Phonebook on iOS, Phonebook on Android) I'm trying to have a synchronized place for them all (CardDAV server with vCards).

However when exporting iOS contacts iCloud only exports the text data, none of the photos get included.

Right now the master data are on my iOS device. I've synced them to iCloud. From the web version of iCloud (where I can see the pictures) I've gone through the `contact app > select all > export to vCard`.

But nontheless, the photos are not included in the exported file.

How can I export them with photos included? I know it can be done with the `PHOTO` field of vCard in base64 format, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TB does not provide credentials when fetching the photo. You can see this when you open the Dev tools in TB.

The only option you currently have is to install the BrowseInTab extension, restart TB, then login to iCloud.com (right-click on a mail containing the icloud.com link and select browse in tab). You will then see that TB correctly fetches and displays the photos in iCloud contacts.

It would be quite simple for TB to correctly fetch the photos. All it needs to do is to add the CardDAV user name and password to the HTTP request when fetching the photo; no need to login to icloud.com this way.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is not in Thunder Bird, but in iCloud export feature. I've edited my question for clarification.